# Tracking specific colours using webcam

Tags: matlab, rgb, tracking

I am trying to figure out how to track different colours (eg. purple/orange) using my webcam. Currently I followed this tutorial:[Tracking red colour](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDUQFjADahUKEwi8vNL8k_bHAhUKbxQKHbGLB68&url=http%3A%2F%2Farindambose.com%2Fblog%2F%3Fp%3D72&usg=AFQjCNFREUxYEyuBNTeLKdtvSCIfypcCOA&sig2=IJFxPWQxbu0CiiiXxx0kyA) and have used the code from here: [red-object tracking](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28757-tracking-red-color-objects-using-matlab). However, using these I can only track red, green or blue by switching the channels. Can someone guide me on how I can use the code in link 2, but track intermediate colours such as purple, orange, pink etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your image to hsv with rgb2hsv. Then threshold based on hue (first) channel. The resulting mask would be used exactly as red channel mask.

Comment: Note, however that you might not be happy with the results and will have to put some conditions on other channels too. After that you might still be unhappy and will want to do e.g. histogram backprojection and meanshift tracking (google that). And even after that you might still be unhappy and want to use more sophisticated features to calculate your aprioiri probabilities (backprojections). So yeah... there's no limit to perfection

Comment: So for example to choose orange, should I find the hue value which represents the orange colour? What about the Saturation and value? Thanks.

Comment: @Sambas23 The idea of HSV space is that the color information is described totally in H, and S and V are "light" and "amount of color". But different colors are described by changing H only.

Comment: @Sambas23 Yes, you should define hue *range* that represents "orange". You can use a [color picker](https://www.google.com/search?q=color+picker&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) application for this. Now about saturation and value. You want them to be reasonably high, because darker pixels might be of "orange" hue due to noise and "inhomogenity" of hsv color space. You could use a color picker to define S and V *range* as well, however if your lighting changes on a real object , those values will drift away, so it is better just to limit them from below.